# Pillow on Mac Book Pro retina displays

Tags: python, selenium, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to take a screenshot of a specific web element using Selenium and Pillow on Python 2.7. The code I have seems to be able to take the screenshot and then crop the image but it is actually not cropping at the exact location of the element. After researching I found that this could be happening due to the dpi used by the Mac Book Pro retina display but I haven´t found a workaround for this.

What could be the best way to handle this "issue" with the retina display and PIL?

This is the code I am using:

```
try:
    #Wait until finishing loading
    waitElement = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='someElement']/span/input[2]"))
    )
    try:
            #Go to trends report
            driver.get("https://somewebsite.com/trends")
            waitElement = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Totals"))
            )

            try:

                    summary = driver.find_element_by_id("Totals")
                    driver.save_screenshot("sc.png")
                    location = summary.location
                    size = summary.size
                    x = location['x']
                    y = location['y']
                    w = size['width']
                    h = size['height']
                    width = x + w
                    height = y + h
                    im = Image.open('sc.png')
                    im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
                    im.save('summary.png')

            except NoSuchElementException:
                    print("Something")
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Something")
finally:
       driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this (broken screenshot issue in case of ratina display on mac)  & solved it using

Snippet I used for this

//basically , here I am using 'devicePixelRatio' to calculate proper width/height

```
    WebElement ele = findElement(By.xpath(webElementXpath));
    Point point = ele.getLocation();
    int devicePixelRatio = Integer.parseInt(returnExecuteJavaScript("return window.devicePixelRatio"));
    int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth() * devicePixelRatio;
    int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight() * devicePixelRatio;
    // ....... for cropping stuff , you can use your own code
```

Comment: Thank you sjethvani. It worked after taking the devicePixelRatio into consideration. The only difference from your code (besides the obvious that I am using Python) is that I had to also multiply the location of the element with the devicePixelRatio.

Comment: Nice to see that it worked in your case . Yeah the only reason of fetching devicePixelRatio is that we want it to multiple with our element's location(width,hight) , which is what I am doing . You can see multiplication with devicePixelRatio in my above snippet.